# Google Plus API Age Range Max Age

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I'm using the following API to get users age range from their Google account:

```
Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
AgeRange ageRange = currentPerson.getAgeRange();
if(ageRange != null) {
   if(ageRange.hasMax())
      max = ageRange.getMax();
   if(ageRange.hasMin())
      min = ageRange.getMin();
}
```

Strangely almost all of the users who's age is greater than `21` have no `max age`, and always report the `min age` as `21`,

<strike>However in my analytics reports there are some exceptions, there are some users that also report 33,27,45,36,58,64 as thier min age, so I guess it's not a permission issue</strike>. my mistake there are only 2 values that the user can get, 18 or 21

Am I doing something wrong?